# Image zoom and panning

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, panning

I want to implement zooming and panning functionality to image(png/svg/jpeg etc.) using javascript/jquery.

There are lot of options available for normal zooming/panning but my requirement is a a bit complex as below:
In the main image(to be zoomed/panned) there are many small images which are already draggable.

My aim is to achieve zooming/panning of the main image along with the small images in the main image. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preferences, but as I've found on of the best implementations for zooming is:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp